# Trying to implement TextBox Error message on MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using MFC.

I'm trying to implement validate text box with error icon message.
i.e:
[image]

But when i click on the textbox the 'x' icon dissapear.
What i'm trying:

```
m_myXIcon->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

How can i solve it?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Probably, you will have to write a similar code to display the icon in the `OnClick` event of the TextBox?

Comment: May be you have a problem with the Z-Order. The icon should be part of the element you are showing.

Comment: @TheApache, the icon display always by default but dissapear when i clicked on the textbox

Comment: @xMRi, whats mean "should be part of the element...", how? :)

Comment: @Evyatar , I see, Can you please post a  **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code** to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @TheApache, if have a simple dialog with textbox and bitmap.

Comment: Have you given any thought to changing the way you render the validation?  Using a red background to indicate an invalid value would probably be easier to implement.

Comment: It looks like your textbox overlaps the bitmap image (and vice versa). And now your siblings both are fighting to be on top of each other. The outcome is not very well defined. Only guarantee: It's not going to be pretty.

Comment: When you create a window you have to define a parent. The sequence of all sibblings are called Z-Order. The Z-Order defined by the creation sequence or by SetWindowPos. As  IInspectable wrote: the textbox and the icon seam to be sibblings so the overlap. If the icon would be a child of the textbox, it would be above the textbox.

Comment: @IInspectable - it can be pretty, as the `EDIT` control specifically supports reserving left and right margins for such purposes; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the text area doesn't overlap your icon. For this, use [CEdit::SetMargins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyc8t6cd.aspx)

> **CEdit::SetMargins**
>
> Call this method to set the left and right margins of this edit
>   control. Syntax
>
> ```
> void SetMargins(
>    UINT nLeft,
>    UINT nRight 
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> nLeft
>
> ```
> The width of the new left margin, in pixels.
> ```
>
> nRight
>
> ```
> The width of the new right margin, in pixels.
> ```